# What is the number of ways of choosing 70 balls from a jar with 30 red balls, 40 blue balls, and 50 green balls?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, generating-functions

I encountered this question in undergrad intro combinatorics class and my professor showed us how to use generating expressions to get the answer (it should be 1061).

My question has two parts:

1. Is there anyway to solve this problem from first principles without generating expressions? (I'm not looking for some complicated analytic expression, but an actual exact result)
2. Using generating expressions, what's the *intuition* behind each step of the process of solving?

I realize this is a bulky question, so please feel free to answer either part (or both) in full or just leave whatever thoughts you may have.

Comment: You can use the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.  Find the number of solutions of the equation $x_r + x_b + x_g = 70$ in the nonnegative integers without restrictions, then remove those solutions which violate one or more of the restrictions $x_r \leq 30$, $x_b \leq 40$, $x_g \leq 50$.  In this case, it is not possible for more than one condition to be violated at a time since $31 + 41 = 72 > 70$.

Comment: Using that approach, it leads to the expression $\binom{72}{2}-\binom{41}{2}-\binom{31}{2}-\binom{21}{2}$ which is indeed equal to $1061$

Comment: That's so interesting, @N.F.Taussig! Could you elaborate more on how you would use this technique to get a full solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regard to the first question, if we let $x_r, x_b,$ and $x_g$ represent, respectively, the number of red, blue, and green balls selected, then the number of ways we can select $70$ balls from the jar containing $30$ red, $40$ blue, and $50$ green balls is the number of solutions of the equation
$$x_r + x_b + x_g = 70 \tag{1}$$
in the nonnegative integers subject to the restrictions $x_r \leq 30, x_b \leq 40, x_g \leq 50$.

If we initially ignore the restrictions on $x_r, x_b,$ and $x_g$, equation $1$ is an equation in the nonnegative integers.  A particular solution of equation $1$ corresponds to the placement of two addition signs in a row of $70$ ones, with the number of ones to the left of the first addition sign representing the number of red balls selected, the number of ones between the two addition signs representing the number of blue balls selected, and the number of ones to the right of the second addition sign representing the number of green balls selected.  Therefore, the number of solutions of equation $1$ is the number of ways we can select two of the $72$ positions required for $70$ ones and two addition signs to be filled with addition signs, which is
$$\binom{70 + 3 - 1}{3 - 1} = \binom{72}{2}$$

In general, the number of ways $k$ objects can be selected from $n$ types of objects without restrictions is the number of solutions of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \cdots + x_n = k$$
in the nonnegative integers, which is
$$\binom{k + n - 1}{n - 1}$$
since we must select which $n - 1$ of the $k + n - 1$ positions required for $k$ ones and $n - 1$ addition signs will be filled with addition signs.

However, we must remove those solutions of equation $1$ which violate one or more of the restrictions $x_r \leq 30, x_b \leq 40, x_g \leq 50$.  Observe that it is not possible to violate two or more of the restrictions simultaneously since $31 + 41 = 72 > 70$.

Suppose $x_r > 30$.  Then $x_r' = x_r - 31$ is a nonnegative integer.  Substituting $x_r' + 31$ for $x_r$ in equation $1$ yields
\begin{align*}
x_r' + 31 + x_b + x_g & = 70\\
x_r' + x_b + x_g & = 39 
\end{align*}
which is an equation in the nonnegative integers with
$$\binom{39 + 3 - 1}{3 - 1} = \binom{41}{2}$$
solutions.

As you should verify, there are
$$\binom{31}{2}$$
solutions of equation $1$ which violate the restriction that $x_b \leq 40$ and
$$\binom{21}{2}$$
solutions of equation $1$ which violate the restriction that $x_g \leq 50$.

Thus, by the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, the number of ways we can select $70$ balls from the jar containing $30$ red, $40$ blue, and $50$ green balls is
$$\binom{72}{2} - \binom{41}{2} - \binom{31}{2} - \binom{21}{2} = 1061$$

Comment: Would we still be able to use this method if we added another category of balls (say we also had 30 white balls in our jar, so $x_w \leq 30$) and we still wanted to draw 70 balls total? Would this mean that it would be possible to violate more than one restriction simultaneously? If so, would that mean we couldn't use this method? If not, what's an example of a modification to this problem that would make this method impossible to use (if it's ever impossible)?

Comment: If there were also $30$ white balls, we could still apply the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.  Note, however, that our new equation would be $x_r + x_b + x_g + x_w = 70$, which has $\binom{70 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} = \binom{73}{3}$ solutions, of which $\binom{39 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} = \binom{42}{3}$ violate the restriction that $x_r \leq 30$, $\binom{42}{3}$ violate the restriction that $x_w \leq 30$, $\binom{32}{3}$ violate the restriction that $x_b \leq 40$, and $\binom{22}{3}$ violate the restriction that $x_g \leq 50$.  See my next comment.

Comment: However, if we subtract those that violate these four restrictions from the total, we will have subtracted those cases in which both the restrictions $x_r \leq 30$ and $x_w \leq 30$ are violated twice, once each when we subtracted those solutions which violate the restrictions $x_r \leq 30$ and $x_w \leq 30$.  We only want to subtract them once, so we must add them to the total.  If $x_r > 30$ and $x_w > 30$, let $x_r' = x_r - 31$ and $x_2 \leq 30$.  Substituting $x_r' + 31$ for $x_r$ and $x_w' + 31$ for $x_w$ in the equation $x_r + x_b + x_g + x_w = 70$ yields $x_r' + x_b + x_g + x_w' = 8$.

Comment: Since the preceding equation has $\binom{8 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} = \binom{11}{3}$ solutions, we obtain $$\binom{73}{3} - 2\binom{42}{3} - \binom{32}{3} - \binom{22}{3} + \binom{11}{3}$$ ways to select $70$ balls from a jar containing $30$ red, $40$ blue, $50$ green, and $30$ white balls.  See the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  Observe that all the other possible pairs of intersections cannot occur, so those terms are equal to zero.

Answer (score 3):

The inclusion-exclusion approach has already been covered in the comments.  For the generating function approach, we have three decisions: how many red, blue, and green to choose.  Each term of the sums $x^0+x^1+\dots+x^{30}$, $x^0+x^1+\dots+x^{40}$, and $x^0+x^1+\dots+x^{50}$ records the number of red, blue, and green, respectively. Choosing $r$ red, $b$ blue, and $g$ green yields $r+b+g$ balls in total, and multiplication of the three sums yields corresponding terms of the form $x^r x^b x^g=x^{r+b+g}$.  So the generating function for the number $a_n$ of ways to choose $n$ balls is
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n 
&= (x^0+x^1+\dots+x^{30})(x^0+x^1+\dots+x^{40})(x^0+x^1+\dots+x^{50}) \\
&= \frac{1-x^{31}}{1-x}\cdot\frac{1-x^{41}}{1-x}\cdot\frac{1-x^{51}}{1-x}
\end{align}
You want the coefficient of $x^{70}$, which turns out to be $a_{70}=1061$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you please explain more of your intuition? I get that taking these steps makes the math work, but the *why* is still unclear. Like what does $x^40$ in represent? I know it means we have 1 way of choosing 40 balls from our 40 blue balls, but that's not entirely illuminating, because it leads me to wonder: what does it mean to multiply sums of ways of choosing things? What are the exponents beyond a convenient algebraic tool? If we only care about the coefficients, could we express the function somehow else? If so, how?